# Spring-boot: Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I've recently run into an error in a spring-boot application, as follows:

````
2021/12/30 12:26:00.004 | ERROR | taskScheduler-2 | o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] | Unknown column 'remoteappt0_.productCode' in 'field list'
2021/12/30 12:26:00.006 | ERROR | taskScheduler-2 | o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler] | Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:279)```

...
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy218.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.sick.ap.components.broker.service.RemoteAppTokenService.getRemoteApps(RemoteAppTokenService.java:254)
    at com.sick.ap.components.broker.config.TokenManagerScheduler.RemoteAppTokenAutoRefresh(TokenManagerScheduler.java:36)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor519.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
... 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'remoteappt0_.productCode' in 'field list'
````

Here's the part of the service class making the invocation:

```
    @Override
    public List<RemoteAppTokenEntity> getRemoteApps() {
        return (List<RemoteAppTokenEntity>) remoteAppTokenRepository.findAll();
    }
```

This is the Entity class :

```
/**
 * The Class RemoteAppTokenEntity.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "ap_login_remote_app_token", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "url", "userName" }) })
public class RemoteAppTokenEntity implements Serializable {

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2527642887887743421L;

    /** The id. */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    /** The user name. */
    @Column(name = "userName", nullable = false)
    private String userName;

    /** The pass word. */
    @Column(name = "passWord", nullable = false)
    private String passWord;

    /** The refresh token. */
    @Column(name = "refreshToken", nullable = false)
    private String refreshToken;

    /** The token type. */
    @Column(name = "tokenType", nullable = false)
    private String tokenType;

    /** The token value. */
    @Column(name = "tokenValue", nullable = false)
    private String tokenValue;

    /** The token expiration. */
    @Column(name = "tokenExpiration", nullable = false)
    private Date tokenExpiration;

    /** The created by. */
    @Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false)
    protected String createdBy;

    /** The created at. */
    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
    protected Date createdAt;

    /** The updated by. */
    @Column(name = "updated_by", nullable = false)
    protected String updatedBy;

    /** The updated at. */
    @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false)
    protected Date updatedAt;

    /** The url. */
    @Column(name = "url", nullable = false)
    private String url;
    
    /** The product code. */
    @Column(name = "productCode", nullable = false)
    private String productCode;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new remote app token entity.
     */
    public RemoteAppTokenEntity() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a new remote app token entity.
     *
     * @param id the id
     * @param userName the user name
     * @param passWord the pass word
     * @param refreshToken the refresh token
     * @param tokenType the token type
     * @param tokenValue the token value
     * @param tokenExpiration the token expiration
     * @param createdBy the created by
     * @param createdAt the created at
     * @param updatedBy the updated by
     * @param updatedAt the updated at
     * @param url the url
     * @param productCode the product code
     */
    public RemoteAppTokenEntity(Long id, String userName, String passWord, String refreshToken, String tokenType,
            String tokenValue, Date tokenExpiration, String createdBy, Date createdAt, String updatedBy, Date updatedAt,
            String url, String productCode) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.passWord = passWord;
        this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
        this.tokenType = tokenType;
        this.tokenValue = tokenValue;
        this.tokenExpiration = tokenExpiration;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
        this.url = url;
        this.productCode = productCode;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the id.
     *
     * @return the id
     */
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the id.
     *
     * @param id the new id
     */
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the user name.
     *
     * @return the user name
     */
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the user name.
     *
     * @param userName the new user name
     */
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the pass word.
     *
     * @return the pass word
     */
    public String getPassWord() {
        return passWord;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the pass word.
     *
     * @param passWord the new pass word
     */
    public void setPassWord(String passWord) {
        this.passWord = passWord;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the refresh token.
     *
     * @return the refresh token
     */
    public String getRefreshToken() {
        return refreshToken;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the refresh token.
     *
     * @param refreshToken the new refresh token
     */
    public void setRefreshToken(String refreshToken) {
        this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the token type.
     *
     * @return the token type
     */
    public String getTokenType() {
        return tokenType;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the token type.
     *
     * @param tokenType the new token type
     */
    public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
        this.tokenType = tokenType;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the token value.
     *
     * @return the token value
     */
    public String getTokenValue() {
        return tokenValue;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the token value.
     *
     * @param tokenValue the new token value
     */
    public void setTokenValue(String tokenValue) {
        this.tokenValue = tokenValue;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the token expiration.
     *
     * @return the token expiration
     */
    public Date getTokenExpiration() {
        return tokenExpiration;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the token expiration.
     *
     * @param tokenExpiration the new token expiration
     */
    public void setTokenExpiration(Date tokenExpiration) {
        this.tokenExpiration = tokenExpiration;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the created by.
     *
     * @return the created by
     */
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the created by.
     *
     * @param createdBy the new created by
     */
    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the created at.
     *
     * @return the created at
     */
    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the created at.
     *
     * @param createdAt the new created at
     */
    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the updated by.
     *
     * @return the updated by
     */
    public String getUpdatedBy() {
        return updatedBy;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the updated by.
     *
     * @param updatedBy the new updated by
     */
    public void setUpdatedBy(String updatedBy) {
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the updated at.
     *
     * @return the updated at
     */
    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the updated at.
     *
     * @param updatedAt the new updated at
     */
    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the url.
     *
     * @return the url
     */
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the url.
     *
     * @param url the new url
     */
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the serialversionuid.
     *
     * @return the serialversionuid
     */
    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
    

    /**
     * @return the productCode
     */
    public String getProductCode() {
        return productCode;
    }

    /**
     * @param productCode the productCode to set
     */
    public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RemoteAppTokenEntity [id=" + id + ", userName=" + userName + ", passWord=" + passWord
                + ", refreshToken=" + refreshToken + ", tokenType=" + tokenType + ", tokenValue=" + tokenValue
                + ", tokenExpiration=" + tokenExpiration + ", createdBy=" + createdBy + ", createdAt=" + createdAt
                + ", updatedBy=" + updatedBy + ", updatedAt=" + updatedAt + ", url=" + url + ", productCode="
                + productCode + "]";
    }

}
```

Here is a mysql dump of table (currently empty):

[image: MySql dump of file]

The class generating the error invoked by a scheduler class on startup in this method:

```
    /**
     * Remote app token auto refresh.
     */
    @Scheduled(cron = "${scheduler.remoteAppTokenAutoRefresh.timer}")
    public void RemoteAppTokenAutoRefresh() {
        List<RemoteAppTokenEntity> remoteAppList = remoteAppTokenService.getRemoteApps();
        remoteAppList.stream().forEach(remoteAppToken -> {
            try {
                remoteAppTokenService.remoteAppTokenRefreshAndUpdate(remoteAppToken);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("Error Occurred in {} Remote app token refresh and update proccess",
                        remoteAppToken.getUrl());
                LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
                LOGGER.debug(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        });
    }
```

I've tried dump the SQL statements, but it's not showing the one from this application, I think because it's a dependency of the end application.

Any ideas what the problem might be? I've been trying some things, but so far no luck.

Full stack trace:

```
2021/12/30 12:26:00.004 | ERROR | taskScheduler-2 | o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] | Unknown column 'remoteappt0_.productCode' in 'field list'
2021/12/30 12:26:00.006 | ERROR | taskScheduler-2 | o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler] | Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:279)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy218.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.sick.ap.components.broker.service.RemoteAppTokenService.getRemoteApps(RemoteAppTokenService.java:254)
    at com.sick.ap.components.broker.config.TokenManagerScheduler.RemoteAppTokenAutoRefresh(TokenManagerScheduler.java:36)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor519.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2173)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1936)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1898)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2695)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2678)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2512)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2507)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1511)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1561)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1529)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:306)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:73)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor343.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'remoteappt0_.productCode' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:536)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:115)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:1983)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1826)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1923)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    ... 59 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I added the full stack trace at the bottom of the post, and the missing,  relevant ones into the partial one at the top.

Comment: Might be a bug with mysql: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1689? Have you maybe tried to restart your database (if possible).

Comment: This is working. I did a bunch of things, mainly rebuilding all the dependencies and switching to another project. I also restarted mysql, and although I don't *think* it was working right after that, I'm not positive. So if you want, post the answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I think it would be best if you add your steps (even if you cannot pinpoint what fixed it) as an answer.